# strange way of passing arguments in express.js source code

Tags: javascript, function, express

When I was looking for source code of express router i saw this:

```
    var debug = require('debug')('express:router:route');
```

can someone explain what this way of passing arguments mean?

Answer (score 4):

In Javascript, functions are "first class", meaning they can be passed around like any other values.

`require('debug')` returns a function. As in, the default export of the `debug` npm package is a function, not an object.

That function is then called with the string `"express:router:route"`

A function that takes in some state or config, and returns a function based off that state or config, is [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application). This **isn't** a case of partial application, though, it's just a shorthand for:

```
var debug = require('debug');
debug('express:router:route');
```

`require` isn't a function that's meant to be partially applied, it just means that the `debug` package is returning a function, and it's being executed in place.

Answer (score 3):

This is a technique as a part of functional programming, called currying, where the function has two arguments, and you can pass the first one and the second one separately.

It is a little hard to get your head around, but worth studying

> What is Currying?
>
> Currying is a process in functional programming in
>   which we can transform a function with multiple arguments into a
>   sequence of nesting functions. It returns a new function that expects
>   the next argument inline. It keeps returning a new function (that
>   expects the current argument, like we said earlier) until all the
>   arguments are exhausted. The arguments are kept "alive"(via closure)
>   and all are used in execution when the final function in the currying
>   chain is returned and executed.

More info here: https://blog.bitsrc.io/understanding-currying-in-javascript-ceb2188c339

Comment: I edited my answer, i'm pretty sure this isn't really partial application/currying, since require is just for module loading, not something you curry/partially apply

Comment: @AndyRay could you elaborate? I'm certain this is partial application/currying

Comment: Actually it is, because of function chaining, `require ('debug')` returns a function, which you then call again with the parameter

Comment: Well, currying is the *verb* of taking a function with multiple arguments and making it partially applicable, so this isn't currying. "require" is not also a function you partially apply, because it doesn't always return a function. It just happens to look like partial application in this case. It's more obvious it's not partial application if this were done with es6 imports

Comment: I guess more generally, you would **never** write this like `requireAndDo('debug', 'express:router:route');`, which would be the uncurried/unpartially applied form

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `debug` package ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug)):

> `debug` exposes a function; simply pass this function the name of your module, and it will return a decorated version of `console.error` for you to pass debug statements to. This will allow you to toggle the debug output for different parts of your module as well as the module as a whole.

So, `require('debug')` returns a function. That function can be called by doing `require('debug')(some parameter)`. Which means the following is possible (example taken from the `debug` docs linked above):

```
var debug = require('debug')('http')
```

Now the variable `debug` points to the result of calling the function returned `require('debug')`, with the parameter `'http'`.